# Python choices; Having a variable value for number of times the choice can be carried out

Tags: python, random

I'm attempting to keep getting random choices until the condition in the `if` block is met(i.e when three consecutive choices return the same result). 
The challenge is that I don't know how to set the choice to continue until the condition is met because it seems `k` must be specified. Thus, I cannot have a variable value for `k` which is determined by when the condition is met.

```
#import random module
import random

# initiate x which would contain predictions
x = 0

#define prediction; which would continue until 3 consecutive predictions get same outcome
while True:
   x = (random.choices(['H','T'], k = 10 ))
   print(x)
   if x[-3:] == ['H','H','H'] or x[-3:] == ['T','T','T']:
      break
```

Comment: You could just call `random.choice` repeatedly instead inside a loop. `choices` is really for when you know ahead of time how many you need, so it isn't really the right tool here.

Comment: Works like charm. Thanks.